# I cannot figure out the preplexity with this regex

Tags: java, regex, eclipse

I thought I was a regex expert but I don't see why this doesn't work.
I have two strings (these are made up for the example so as not to reveal actual personal data):

*Tom Smith Accounting (200)*, and 
*Bill Jones (15%) Special (310)*

So I want to to get the employee number (you can see that Bill has two numbers in parenthesis).  So I want to get 200 and 310.  I made a loop with the String variable "st" to iterate between the two:

```
public class MyMain {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] str = { "Tom Smith Accounting (200)", "Bill Jones (15%) Special (310)" };

    for (String st : str) {
        String cont = st.replace(".*(", "").replace(").*$", "");
        System.out.println(st + " === " + cont);
    }
 }
}
```

But the results are the same as the original input:

```
Tom Smith Accounting (200) === Tom Smith Accounting (200)
Bob Jones (15%) Special (310) === Bob Jones (15%) Special (310)
```

Using replace like this *String cont = st.replace("(", "");* works by getting rid of just the parenthesis:

```
Tom Smith Accounting (200) === Tom Smith Accounting 200)
Bill Jones (15%) Special (310) === Bill Jones 15%) Special 310)
```

as does *String cont = st.replace(")", "");*

```
Tom Smith Accounting (200) === Tom Smith Accounting (200
Bill Jones (15%) Special (310) === Bill Jones (15% Special (310
```

I feel fairly certain if I did this in ksh in linux (echo | sed 's/.../...' it would work, so what am I doing wrong here?  replaceFirst() does not work either (gives an unclosed group error).

Does anybody see the error?  Is there some other way to pick a number from between parenthesis (like sscanf() in C)?

Comment: `replace` doesn't accept a regex. `replaceAll` does.

Comment: You are trying to dig a well using a pencil!. You will break the *tip* and everything will come crashing down.. Don't use regex for *parsing* (in what looks like *deployment code*)

Comment: Oh and yes I did try escaping them.  (In java you have to use double, like "\\(" like st.replace(".*\\(", "").replace("\\).*$", "")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First mistake: you used replace instead of replaceAll (replace doesn't use Regex)

Second mistake: you didn't escape the `(` and `)` characters.

Third mistake: your first regex is missing a `^` to signify the start of the line.

Fourth mistake: you should use `[^(]` instead of `.`, so it doesn't match open brackets.

Comment: Thanks.  I did add a comment above that I tried escaping them but I think I entered that after you made your comment but before I saw it.  But like you say, I will try replaceAll()

Comment: Ok, yeah, that must have been after I started writing. I'll leave it anyways in since it's not in the question. If that helped you, please accept the answer.

Comment: I am still new at doing this.  I clicked the upward triangle next to the answer.  I guess I need to do something else too.

Comment: @Tony You should see information that to accept any answer you need to wait until your question will be at least 15 minutes old. You can try again now.

Comment: Oh and re #4 I did want it to match "(" because one of those examples had a "(15%)" before the employee number.  I did think of making two methods, one with "notGreedy()" appended to the end of the name of the method.  Oh and yeah one of my trials did have the "^" ;-)

Comment: Thanks for accepting! The triange is an upvote which anyone can do, the check mark is accepting, which only you can do.